# Android: How to open a file from inside your application

Tags: android, file, parsing, browser

I've done my fair share of searching for tutorials and guides online, but the only stuff I have found is from 2007 and out of date.

I wanted to know how to open a file from within my current application. For instance, if I click a "Browse" button, it will start another activity of a default file browser on the device (I don't have to implement my own, right?). Obviously I would need it to return the file so I could parse through it as I pleased.

I figured it would be some for of Intent binded to the the button, but I'm now sure.

Comment: A little late, but there is a [file chooser](http://code.google.com/p/android-filechooser/)…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bad news - there is not a native "file selector".  Good news - [this guy](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/190013-creating-simple-file-chooser/) made one so you don't have to.

Comment: Why is it that on my phone when I go to select a file for some apps, it will give me an option of which file browsing program I want to use to select it?

Comment: They rely on 3rd party options for opening files.  If you didn't have any apps installed that can open files (Astro, OI File Manager, etc) then you're sunk.  I tried doing that in one of my own apps but realized (through Google Analytics) that 90% of the people did not have a file manager available and could not use the application.  I implemented the file manager in the link and cleared up that problem.

Comment: Tried running that application on its own on a 3.0 emulator, but it wouldn't display anything - so I don't know if it is compatible for me.

Comment: Does your emulator have an SD card attached to it?  It needs one of those.

Comment: Yup of course. This is what I get at boot-up: http://img535.imageshack.us/img535/4899/tempwy.jpg

Comment: Ok, do you have anything on the SD card of the emulator?  If you haven't put anything on it, then it will be empty and display as your screen-grab shows.  You can upload through the Eclipse interface.

Comment: Perhaps thats the problem. Still can't push any data on to it through Eclipse though. The permissions are read only. I've recreated the AVD and tried chmod 777 towards it a couple different ways through ADB. This is such a pain...

Comment: I've never had that issue.  I don't have an Android-enabled Eclipse in front of me so I can't be of much help with that.  Once you have that straightened out, it should be pretty smooth from there.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` instead of hard-coding the directory path to the SD card. There also seems to be a problem with getting the exact SD card directory using Android 3.0 and 3.1. I have a test app that reads and writes fine in Android 2.3.3 but the same piece of code doesn't work anymore (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545478/android-3-1-sd-card-emulation).